# Choosing highest ranked ID from a each cell in particular column and assign a new column

Tags: r, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I have a data frame with colnames genes with a score separated with "|"  and alias separated with ";" and I would like to extract a gene name with the highest score in that column except Ensembl ID i.e id starting with ENSG.

```
        chr start   end ID  genes 
0   chr6    30856165    30867931    1007_s_at   DDR1|100.0 ;MIR4640|0.76
1   chr7    73646002    73668732    1053_at RFC2|100.0
2   chr1    161494448   161496380   117_at  ENSG00000273112|100.0 ;HSPA6|100.0
3   chr2    113974939   114036488   121_at  PAX8-AS1|96.21 ;PAX8|100.0 ;RP11-65I12.1|1.1
4   chr6    42140941    42147792    1255_g_at   GUCA1ANB|100.0 ;GUCA1A|100.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
53585   chr11   65357647    65359951    91703_at    EHBP1L1|100.0 ;AP001362.1|55.64
53586   chr19   1554671 1555414 91816_f_at  MEX3D|100.0
53587   chr19   55598669    55599291    91826_at    EPS8L1|100.0
53588   chr1    156622054   156626137   91920_at    BCAN|100.0 ;ENSG00000229953|100.0
53589   chr19   14070797    14072256    91952_at    DCAF15|100.0
```

I tried partitioning the column and then extracting the score from the column and used nested for loop for item in Each_gene_score and split item based on the pipe and saved the value in dict.

Any better and faster way to accomplish it?  Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Please provide data in a more usable format. For R, `dput(head(x))` (or some representative and sufficient sample, not just the top 6 rows, but not all 50K+ rows). As for your code, have you tried `strsplit`?

Answer (score 0):

```r
sapply(
  strsplit(dat$genes, ";"),
  function(z) {
    z <- z[!grepl("^ENSG", z)]
    gene <- strsplit(z, "\\|")
    tryCatch(sapply(gene, `[[`, 1)[which.max(as.numeric(sapply(gene, `[[`, -1)))],
             error = function(e) NA_character_)
  })
#  [1] "DDR1"     "RFC2"     "HSPA6"    "PAX8"     "GUCA1ANB" "EHBP1L1"  "MEX3D"    NA         "EPS8L1"   "BCAN"     "DCAF15"
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(genes = c("DDR1|100.0;MIR4640|0.76", "RFC2|100.0", "ENSG00000273112|100.0;HSPA6|100.0", "PAX8-AS1|96.21;PAX8|100.0;RP11-65I12.1|1.1", "GUCA1ANB|100.0;GUCA1A|100.0", "EHBP1L1|100.0;AP001362.1|55.64", "MEX3D|100.0", ".", "EPS8L1|100.0", "BCAN|100.0;ENSG00000229953|100.0", "DCAF15|100.0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Thanks,  this outputs the list of the genes instead of new column in df!

Comment: You said *"extract a gene name with the highest score"*, this extracts the leading string. Perhaps you should include usable data and expected output as previously requested.